# Thrive Themes responsive issue

Tags: css, wordpress, drag-and-drop, wordpress-theming

Im making a landing page with Thrive Themes Content Builder.

http://www.fitmateptonline.com/kitchen-rescue-pak/

Everything is fine on desktop but when you open it on mobile, its messed up.

I tried to use @media in the custom css code, but it doesnt work as it should. Asked the support of thrive themes, they gave me this code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px)  {
    #tve_editor > div.tve_lp_header.tve_empty_dropzone.tve_content_width > div > div > div > div > div.thrv_wrapper.thrv_page_section > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(1) > div {
        margin-top: -160px !important;
    }
}
```

With or without the extremely long selector they gave me, the @media seems not working.

I have been reading in their knowledge base and forums for 8 days now..still no answer anywhere. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

well, it's working fine on my phone.

can you attach a screenshot for us to see the issue.

Thanks

Comment: I dont know how, but it managed to be fixed by itself...I really didnt do anything, its from the Thrive Themes builder I believe